# How to determine the run time of this solution to duplicate permutations?

Tags: algorithm, runtime

I know that the number of permutations on n distinct objects is n!, so worst case, the below is n! in run-time. But what about average case? I have a solution for handling permuting elements of an array with duplicates (e.g. - [1, 2, 2, 3]), but I'm not sure how to determine the average case runtime. Could someone please explain this to me?

```
import collections
class Permutations(object):
    def permuteUnique(self, nums):
        ctr = collections.Counter(nums)
        res = []
        self.backtrack(res, [], nums, len(nums), ctr)
        return res

    def backtrack(self, res, temp, nums, check, ctr):
        if check == 0:
            res.append(temp)
        else:
            for key,v in ctr.items():
                if ctr[key] == 0:
                    continue
                ctr[key] -= 1
                self.backtrack(res, temp + [key], nums, check - 1, ctr)
                ctr[key] += 1
```

Comment: You cannot determine the run time without knowing the distribution of duplicate elements: "average" is dependent on that PDF.

Comment: @Prune what if for example you have all 1's?

Comment: If you have all 1's, you have a single output.  All you need is the time to detect a single value and dump the one permutation, which is **O**(N) on the size of the list.  I'm not sure what sort of answer you want for that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have an array with `k` distinct values occurring `m_1`, `m_2`, ..., `m_k` times.  Let `n = m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_k`.  The number of arrangements is the number of permutations of `n` distinct things divided by the number of permutations that give the same arrangement.  Since each of the distinct values could appear in any order and give the same arrangement, that works out to be `n! / (m_1! * m_2! * ... * m_k!)`

If you wish to go from this exact formula to some kind of useful approximation, I would suggest using [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), sticking in the assumptions that you want, and going from there.